# Python and OpenCV - Improving my lane detection algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I'll need to detect road lane from a video. Here is my way of doing it.

1. Determine the Region of Interest (ROI) by slicing the image (focus the middle part)
2. Grayscale the ROI
3. Equalized the grayscaled ROI with `cv2.equalizeHist`
4. Apply Gaussian blur to (3)
5. Threshold (4) by using `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`
6. Skeletonize (5) by using `skimage.morphology.skeletonize`
7. Apply the `cv2.HoughLines` on (6)

For the `cv2.HoughLines`, I set up so that:

1. If `rho` is positive (which means the straight line is sloping to the right (bottom-up), it will only draw the line if it is at certain angles (I set up the range of the angle))
2. If `rho` is negative (straight line is sloping to the left (bottom-up), it will only draw the line if it is at certain angles)

This is my code for drawing the lines:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(image_bin, 1, np.pi/180, 50)
    try:
        range = lines.shape[0]
    except AttributeError:
        range = 0

    for i in xrange(range):
        for rho, theta in lines[i]:
            if rho > 0 and (np.pi*1/10 < theta < np.pi*4/10):
                a = np.cos(theta)
                b = np.sin(theta)
                x0 = a * rho
                y0 = b * rho
                x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
                y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
                x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
                y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

                cv2.line(roi, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0))

            if rho < 0 and (np.pi*7/10 < theta < np.pi*9/10):
                a = np.cos(theta)
                b = np.sin(theta)
                x0 = a * rho
                y0 = b * rho
                x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
                y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
                x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
                y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

                cv2.line(roi, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0))
```

If I didn't do what I just did above for the `cv2.HoughLines` function, I believe there will be a lot of unneeded lines drawn.

After adjusting the parameters and such, I got a quite good result but that is for just one picture. I don't think it will be that good for a video that will keep changing. 
What bother me the most is about my algorithm for drawing the needed lines (that is the road lane). Is there any better way? At least better than mine.

This is my result:

The original image:
[image: The original image]

Equalized histogram, thresholded, and skeletonized image of the ROI:
[image: Equalized Histogram, thresholded, and skeletonized]

Final result:
[image: Final result]

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend considering using the Probabilistic Hough Line Transform for your application.  In OpenCV's Python API, it's implemented in the function, `cv2.HoughLinesP`.  That will actually give you line segments so you won't need to calculate the endpoints.  It's also much faster than the standard Hough Line Transform.

There are a few trade-offs though.  For example, you may need to add logic to stitch line segments together.  On the other hand, I've found that that's not really a bad thing.  One of my toy projects (a self-driving miniature bus), used this approach, and having separate line segments to stitch together made it easier to deal with curved roads in which the standard hough line transform won't give you any lines at all.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Regarding the details of line segment "stitching", it depends on what you're looking to accomplish.  If you just want to display the road, and you're satisfied with there being some gaps between line segments, you may not need to do any stitching - just display all the line segments. In my application, I needed to determine the curvature of the lane, so I did some stitching to build up a model of each road lane which would include the average slope of the lane - that was used as input to a module responsible for controlling a servo to move the wheels accordingly.

By "stitching" I don't mean anything particularly sophisticated, but I'm not aware of any particular OpenCV functions to accomplish it.  I just needed a way of associated line segments that were part of the same lane.  So I processed the line segments returned from `HoughLinesP` from the top of the image working downward, and used each line segment's slope and y-intercept to determine where the line segments would intersect.

Comment: How can I 'stitch' the lines? Sorry, still a beginner in both programming and image processing.

Comment: I added some notes.  Sorry for not providing any code.  It's in C++, and the particular implementation is very different from yours - basically, I just don't have enough time to adapt it for your application.